# 2001 Jeep Grand Cherokee - What is Involved With Replacing the Negative Battery Cable?

Tags: electrical, battery, jeep, grand-cherokee, battery-cable

We have replaced the alternator and battery but still have problem with starting. It takes a jump and starts every time but after you park and come back, it won't start again. I has been to the shop three times (2 different ones).

Now to Firestone where they say it's a frayed negative battery cable, which is too short to fix and needs to be replaced. They won't do it, they say to take it to a dealer and that it's expensive.

What is involved with the job? Are there specialized tools required to do it right, or is it something that a home mechanic might consider taking on?

Comment: Is it the 4.0L I6 or the V8? Looking at a picture for the I6, both cables (positive & negative) are loomed together. I don't think it would be particularly hard, but it would take some attention to detail and patience. I found the one for the I6 on [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/Cherokee-Battery-Wiring-Negative-Positive/dp/B00HUZA8OQ), so you can look for yourself. I would bet the V8 one is very similar (if not identical).

Comment: Welcome to the site. As it stands, this question is not a good fit here as it can generate opinion. What's easy for you may be difficult for someone else, and what's expensive for person X can be loose change for Y. I suggest you rephrase the question to ask for the steps involved in changing out the wire, else this question will get closed.

Comment: You might want to voltage drop test the negative battery cable before you replace it. Hook one end of a multimeter up to the negative terminal and the other to the other end of the cable. Then crank. What's the reading? Also the frayed cable sounds like BS. they may be talking about an engine ground strap that's a flat braided deal and goes from the engine to the firewall or frame. Can you take a picture of what they're talking about? Did they test the car for draw?